# How to setup Commitment use discounts on google?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create a blog on GCP using [ghost cms](https://ttps://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bitnami-launchpad/ghost) with a bitnami server. I recently found commitment discounts.

I know bitanmi provides a commitment discount on that. But my website is 15 months old maybe for that reason a commitment discount is not added to my bills and my bill amount is very high forme. So that's the reason I try to set up my own commitment discount for my blog.

I config my blog comes to the default configuration. My machine type is g1-small and uses 10 GB storage.

Fill in the information on the commitment page. Them click to purchase button, I face an error.

```
Creating commitment "commitment-1" failed. Error: invalid value for type Long
```

Guide me on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to use [Committed Discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts).

You've mention that you are using `g1-small`

> My machine type is g1-small and uses 10 GB storage

In the [Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#restrictions) part you will find:

> Committed use discounts do not apply to [preemptible VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance), [N1 shared-core machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore), or [extended memory](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type#extendedmemory).

`g1-small` is a `shared-core` machine type. You can confirm it [in this docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_types) or in the `GCP UI` like below (view from Compute Engine)
[image]

In [Commitment types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#commitment_types) you can find information on what resources can be `committed`. On the bottom of this part you also can find information that `g1-small` cannot be committed.

> You can't purchase commitments for `f1-micro`, or `g1-small` machine types or for the sole-tenant premium charge.

Regarding storage, only `Local SSD` disk can be committed and those are `375 GB` as per [About local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd) documentation.

> Each local SSD is 375 GB in size, but you can attach a maximum of 24 local SSD partitions for 9 TB per instance.

**To sum up**

With your current setup you are not able to use `Committed Discounts`. You would need to use different machine type.

Comment: How to provide bitnami discount in ghost cms

Comment: When you are using marketplace - Ghost packaged by Bitnami, you have pricing, which estimate $18,76 per month but you have `Sustained use discount` which is $5,63 per month. So in general you would pay $13.60 per month. You've asked about GCP committment discount which is not applicable to `shared-core`. So you are asking for GCP discount or this specific Ghost platform discount (if there is one)?